# Automotive AC Diagnosis Chart / Resources

Tags: ac, hvac

Has anyone found a good automotive AC diagnosis chart?  I can find some suggesting pressure ranges, and even temperature and pressure ranges, but I cannot find a good source which also includes diagnosis of dryer, expansion valve, and other components.

Any good recommendations?

Comment: Plot the cycle on an H-S diagram.

Comment: @SolarMike that is a great idea.  I was hopeful that the answers might create a foundation for a FAQ or something similar, which could be of general use to many.  If you have any diagrams, could you include them in an answer, please?

Comment: It was advice for you, any decent thermodynamics textbook has examples.